# How can I choose soundfonts in Qsynth?

Tags: keyboard, midi

I'm using a MIDI Keyboard with Qjackctl and Qsynth. I installed some Soundfonts, but now how can I choose the sound I want to play? For exmaple, Piano, Guitar, Organ, Synth etc... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First you need to import the Soundfonts in Qsynth. To do this press the <kbd>setup</kbd> button and go to the Soundfonts tab. The Soundfonts can be found under `/usr/share/sounds/sf2/`.

Then you can choose which sound to use for each channel. Press the <kbd>channels</kbd> button in Qsynth. A new window will be opened in which you can see all the channels and instruments related to them. Right click on the desired channel and click edit in order to choose the sound.