# Qsynth and Ubuntu Studio 17.10

Tags: software-recommendation

I have Qsynth and 2 soundfonts . Where can I install more soundfonts from?

Comment: Search, soundfonts free https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=soundfonts+free

Comment: Close voters crafted answer

Answer (score 0):

A little digging into sound fonts resulted in finding http://www.hammersound.net/ which has a pretty extensive soundfont library. It's also possible that with sufficient motivation you could create your own by following [the specification.](http://www.synthfont.com/sfspec24.pdf)

I'm anticipating your next question might be [How can i choose soundfont in Qsynth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455842/how-can-i-choose-soundfont-in-qsynth)

Sources:

https://sourceforge.net/p/fluidsynth/wiki/SoundFont/